# Boolean value based on length of other field of row postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I have crated table which stores value and concats another based on event in applictaion
[image: Table look]
I want to set completed value as TRUE once date length of chars exceeds 20, is it possible to do in postgres?
Thanks in advance

I am not sure what to do, I used more detailed functionalities of db more than 3 years ago last time.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Show Postgres version and table definition. Define the task more closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the column `completed` as a generated column and set the generation code based on the length of the `date` column (seems a particularly poor column name). So:

```
create table event_list(id         integer generated always as identity
                                           primary key
                       , date      character varying(100)
                       , completed boolean generated always as (length(date) > 20) stored
                       );
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bogCx6rc).  
The above works in v12 and above. For prior versions you create a trigger on insert and update that sets the value for `completed` column. (included in demo)